# best way to use bootstrap themes from themeforest into Angular

Tags: angular

For my Angular project, I used a pre-existing free theme from ThemeForest but I found it very difficult to manage my js files and CSS files which comes with the theme.

I added it in my `src/assets` folder and then mentioned them in my `app.module.ts` file but not able to get some of the js functionality into my child components.

I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding those css and js file in angular.json file

```
"styles": [
       "src/assets/somestyle.css",
       ],
"scripts": [
       "src/assets/somejs.js"
]
```

and remember to add proper path

Comment: already did it but still child components not able to get it.